# Replace headers by bold in HTML with python

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I have some HTML text like this one:

```
'<H1 LANG="es-ES" CLASS="western" STYLE="text-indent: -0.5cm; line-height: 100%"><FONT FACE="Arial, sans-serif"><FONT SIZE=3>some_text_here</FONT></FONT></H1>'
```

within a larger HTML text. I want to automatically identify all such headers and change them to simple bold text:

```
'<B LANG="es-ES" CLASS="western" STYLE="text-indent: -0.5cm; line-height: 100%"><FONT FACE="Arial, sans-serif"><FONT SIZE=3>some_text_here</FONT></FONT></B>'
```

Using regular expressions are not the best because sometimes the header start and end are on different lines.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` but a easy way is use `re.sub()` in the following form:

```
   html_content = re.sub("<H\d", "<B", html_content)
   html_content = re.sub("<\/H\d>", "</B>", html_content)
```